# Java program to add two numbers represented by linked lists

Tags: java, linked-list

First of all, I found this question on Leetcode.The two digits of the two numbers are stored in reverse order.We have to add them and create a single linked list composed of the sum of the two numbers.Here is the [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/description/) for reference.

```
public class LLAdd {
    static Node head, head1, head2;

    static class Node {
        Node link;
        int data;

        Node(int data){
            this.data = data;
            this.link = null;
        }
    }

public static void printList(Node head){
    Node curr = head;
    while(curr!=null){
        System.out.print(curr.data + "->");
        curr = curr.link;
    }
    System.out.print("NULL \n");
}

public static Node push(int data, Node head){
    Node new_node = new Node(data);
    new_node.link = head;
    head = new_node;
    return head;
}

public static Node addNumbers(){
    Node curr1 = head1, curr2 = head2;

    if(curr1==null) {
        return curr2;
    }
    if(curr2==null) {
        return curr1;
    }

    int data = 0, units = 0, tens = 0;

    while(curr1!=null || curr2!=null){
        data = (curr1!=null ? curr1.data : 0) + (curr2!=null ? curr2.data : 0) + tens;
        units = data % 10;
        tens = data / 10;
        head = push(units, head);
        curr1 = curr1!=null ? curr1.link : null;
        curr2 = curr2!=null ? curr2.link : null;
        if(curr1==null && curr2==null && tens > 0){
            head = push(tens, head);
        }
    }   
    return head;
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    head1 = push(3, head1);
    head1 = push(4, head1);
    head1 = push(2, head1);

    head2 = push(4, head2);
    head2 = push(6, head2);
    head2 = push(5, head2);

    System.out.println("Lists before addition: ");
    printList(head1);
    printList(head2);

    System.out.println("List after addition : ");
    head = addNumbers();
    printList(head);
   }
}
```

Please review this code and suggest better ways to solve this problem.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**Advice 1**

Fix your code indentation. Instead of

```
public class LLAdd {
...
public static void printList(Node head){
...
}
...
}
```

you should have

```
public class LLAd {
    ...
    public static void printList(Node head){
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

**Advice 2**

In method definitions, one, according to common Java coding conventions, must have a single space between parameter-closing `)` and a block-opening `{`. Instead of

```
public static void printList(Node head){
    ...
}
```

you should write

```
public static void printList(Node head) {
    ...                                ^-- Space!
}
```

**Advice 3**

The class name `LLAdd` is really poor. Taking a look of what it does, you could come up with the name, say, `BigInteger`.

**Advice 4**

```
static Node head, head1, head2;
```

This is an anti-pattern since there is only one "instance" of the class. Make these non-static and private instead.

**Advice 5**

```
Node new_node ...
```

Once again, Java coding conventions dictate that the fields/variables are named in CamelCase:

```
Node newNode ...
```

**Advice 6**

```
static class Node {
    Node link;
    int data;

    Node(int data){
        this.data = data;
        this.link = null;
    }
}
```

Make this `private` and `final` since most likely you don't want to shine into the entire package, and you hardly need to derive from that class. Also, I would rename `link` to `next`. Finally for this advice, you don't need `this.link = null;`. Java sets all the object fields to `null` by default.

**Advice 7** In principle, I think you should make your `BigInteger/LLAdd` ***immutable***.

**Advice 8**

```
public static Node push(int data, Node head)...
```

That's is a poor name too. Looking from what it does, I suggest you rename it to `prependDigit`. Also, I believe you would want to check that `data` is within the range 0-9 unless you want to allow dealing with arbitrary radices.

**Advice 9**

Instead of implementing `printList`, I would override `toString`.

**Alternative implementation**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public final class BigInteger {

    private static final class Digit {
        Digit next;
        int digit;

        Digit(char ch) {
            this.digit = ch - '0';
        }

        Digit(int digit) {
            this.digit = digit;
        }
    }

    private Digit leastSignificantDigit;

    public BigInteger(String integerText) {
        checkCharacters(integerText);
        leastSignificantDigit = 
                new Digit(integerText.charAt(integerText.length() - 1));
        Digit head = leastSignificantDigit;

        for (int i = integerText.length() - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
            Digit digit = new Digit(integerText.charAt(i));
            head.next = digit;
            head = digit;
        }
    }

    private BigInteger() {

    }

    public BigInteger add(BigInteger other) {
        Digit digit1 = leastSignificantDigit;
        Digit digit2 = other.leastSignificantDigit;
        BigInteger result = new BigInteger();
        Digit headDigit = null;
        boolean carry = false;

        while (digit1 != null || digit2 != null) {
            int intDigit1 = digit1 == null ? 0 : digit1.digit;
            int intDigit2 = digit2 == null ? 0 : digit2.digit;
            int sum = intDigit1 + intDigit2 + (carry ? 1 : 0);
            carry = sum > 9;
            int currentDigit = carry ? (sum - 10) : sum;
            Digit digit = new Digit(currentDigit);

            if (result.leastSignificantDigit == null) {
                result.leastSignificantDigit = digit;
                headDigit = digit;
            } else {
                headDigit.next = digit;
                headDigit = digit;
            }

            if (digit1 != null) {
                digit1 = digit1.next;
            }

            if (digit2 != null) {
                digit2 = digit2.next; 
            }
        }

        if (carry) {
            headDigit.next = new Digit(1);
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (Digit digit = leastSignificantDigit; 
                digit != null; 
                digit = digit.next) {
            stringBuilder.append((char)('0' + digit.digit));
        }

        return stringBuilder.reverse().toString();
    }

    private void checkCharacters(String integerText) {
        for (char ch : integerText.toCharArray()) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(ch)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "Character '" + ch + "' is not a valid digit.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        BigInteger bi1 = new BigInteger(scanner.nextLine());
        BigInteger bi2 = new BigInteger(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.println(bi1 + " + " + bi2 + " = " + bi1.add(bi2));
    }
}
```